# Automatically increment column based on composite primary key

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have the columns A, B and C. Where A, B and C make up the primary key (composite). What I want to have happen is that whenever I do an insert on A/B, the  column C should increment by one, only for that particular combination.

Esentially C will track the version for the combinations of A/B. Together, all the enries should still all be unique.

This is what I want my table to look like after the inserts:

- [A]_ [B]_ [C]_
- Foo Bar 1
- Foo Bar 2
- Bar Baz 1
- Foo Bar 3
- Bar Baz 2
- Foo Foo 1

I'd basically like a seed of 1 based on the group of A/B.

Any idea of how I can achieve this? I think I'm going to need a trigger of sorts, and then a calculation for the maximum for the current C for columns A/B?

Comment: Yes, such a trigger might help.

Comment: Do not try to force a continuos numbering at data manipulation (INSERT /DELETE /UPDATE) time. Just let 
 sql-server autonumber it and use ROW_NUMBER() OVER() at SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

It is not worth it, under most circumstances.  Guaranteeing a sequential number is rather complicated -- and more so if you take updates and deletes into account.

An alternative approach is to have an identity column as the primary key of the table.  Then, if you want a sequential number, you can use:

```
select a, b, row_number() over (partition by a, b, order by table_id) as c
```

If you really wanted to create such a number, you would need an `insert` trigger which does the calculation -- and locks the entire table in case another operation is inserting the same `a`/`b` values.  You also need triggers for `update`s and `delete`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need a trigger for that. Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tAI_AB]
   ON  [dbo].[AB]
   AFTER INSERT
AS
   DECLARE @A INT;
   DECLARE @B INT;
   DECLARE @C INT;
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
   Set @A = (Select A from inserted);
   Set @B = (Select B from inserted);
   Set @C= (Select isnull(Max(C), 0) From AB where A=@A and B=@B);

   UPDATE AB Set C = @C+1 WHERE A=@A and B=@B and C is null;
END
```

Just change to appropriate types of A and B, and column/table names.